# C7 plugs with 3A fuses

Tags: standard, plug, legal, current-rating

IEC 60320 C7 type plugs seem to be rated at 2.5A, yet they are commonly supplied and used in the UK on cables where the source side plug is fused at 3A. Does this meet standards, and is it legal and safe?

Comment: The best people to ask would be those an an NRTL as they will determine the saftey

Comment: Fuses are easy to change out in most setups so it wouldn't be hard to determine this at the time of testing